# How to create chart through API in apache superset

Tags: apache-superset

I had created dashboard through API in apache superset.I had added chart on that dashboard. But i'm not sure about what to pass in params and query_context in request_body of chart POST API.

POST:/api/v1/chart/

Example:

{

"dashboards": [
1
],
"datasource_id": 1,

"datasource_name": "Test",

"datasource_type": "table",

"params":"",

"query_context": "",

"query_context_generation": true,

"slice_name": "test",

"viz_type": "big_number_total"
}

Someone can share example for what to pass in params and query_context?